# wpml if/else statement in twig

Tags: if-statement, twig, wpml

I have a multi-lingual Wordpress site that uses WPML. One of the plugins I need it to play nice with is written in twig and I’m having trouble making my if/else statement twig-friendly. In php, what I need to say is:

```
<?php if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ): ?>
    English
<?php elseif ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es' ): ?>
    Spanish
<?php endif;?>
```

Can someone help me translate that into twig? I’ve attempted a few things with no luck, one example below.

```
{% if ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' %}
    English
{% elseif ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es' %}
    Spanish
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Which plugin your using which uses twig for its templates

Comment: all in one events calendar